# Можно ли отключить в Word 2016 обращение к левым ресурсом?

Tags: ms-word, office, office365

Например, у меня есть Word в котором что-то используется с какой-то шары(может быть какая-то картинка) и он пытается безуспешно достучаться туда и соответственно сам документ все это время висит и не открывается. Честно, я не разу не дождался пока он откроется, хотя ждал достаточно долго.

Если открыть тот же документ через старый Word, то он достаточно быстро открывается.

Можно ли этот момент как-нибудь настроить? TimeOut адекватный повесить или еще чего?

Comment: можно попробовать отключить в разделе `дополнительное` в подразделе `общее` галку `автоматически обновлять связи при открытии`, может поможет, если не поможет то пишите, будем дальше искать

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko все равно висит сообщение "Обращение: \\Share\Blablabla "